# Memory error allocating list of 11,464,882 empty dicts

Tags: python, list, memory, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm using portable python 2.7.5.1.

The following line:

```
x = [{} for i in range(11464882)]
```

Causes a memory error (with no other messages):

```
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 12, in <module>
MemoryError
>>>
```

Note: there are only comments in lines 1-11.

Decreasing one unit in the funny number above the error disappears.

Considering that 11 million ain't that large, I believe there must be some simple setting that can increase the amount of memory available for my programs.

So, is this something simple I'm missing or an inherent memory limit?

Comment: Trying `x = [{} for i in xrange(11464882)]` and see if the number changes.

Comment: What platform is this on? How much memory do you have? What does `import sys; sys.getsizeof({})` say a dictionary requires in bytes?

Comment: Also, `range(11464882)` creates a list of 11464882 integers. Use `xrange()` instead to avoid using up all that memory.

Comment: On my macbook air with python 2.7.x it requires ~3.5GB of memory.

Comment: Thanks drewk and MartijnPieters, I'm new to python :-)

Comment: Allocating 11 million object at once is a bad idea. You could for example allocate an object when you need to. Also the objects you don't need for now, rather than leave them resident in memory you could serialize them on the disk until you need them, this just an example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On my Mac OS X 10.8.5 64-bit laptop, a `range(11464882)` object requires:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(range(11464882))
91719128
>>> sys.getsizeof(11464881)  # largest number
24
>>> sys.getsizeof(0)         # smalest number
24
>>> 91719128 + (24 * 11464882)  # bytes
366876296
>>> (91719128 + (24 * 11464882)) / (1024.0 ** 2) # mb
349.88050079345703
```

so 350 megabytes of memory.

Here, [`sys.getsizeof()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) returns the memory footprint of the given Python objects *not counting contained values*. So, for a list, it is *just* the memory a list structure requires; bookkeeping information plus 11 million 64-bit pointers.

In addition, that many empty dictionaries take:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof({})
280
>>> 91719128 + 280 * 11464882
3301886088
>>> (91719128 + 280 * 11464882) / (1024.0 ** 2) # mb
3148.923957824707
>>> (91719128 + 280 * 11464882) / (1024.0 ** 3) # gb
3.0751210525631905
```

3 gigabytes of memory. 11 million times 280 bytes *is* a lot space.

Together with other overhead (most likely garbage collection cycle detection, the Python process itself and memoized values), that means you hit your machine's 4GB per-process memory limit.

If you are running a 32-bit binary, sizes will be smaller as you'd only need room for 32-bit pointers, but you also only get 2GB of addressable memory to fit all your objects into.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, you nailed it. In my platform, `{}` takes 140 bytes, so I'm hitting a 2GB barrier I guess. How can I tell if I'm running 32 or 64 bit python? I'm on win7-64.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft: look at `sys.maxint`; 2147483647 means you are running a 32-bit python.